# GOOGLEFINANCE "priceopen" doesn't work? Alternative?

Tags: google-sheets

According to the official documentation: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281

I should be able to do `=GOOGLEFINANCE("goog","priceopen",TODAY()-30,TODAY())`

However, when I do that, I get an error message saying `Error: Function GOOGLEFINANCE parameter 2 value is invalid for the symbol specified.`

Why is this happening?  Any work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("goog","open",TODAY()-30,TODAY())
```

`priceopen` is for real time data, so is not compatible with a range of dates.

Comment: Thanks pnuts! Totally missed the other attributes.